# OpenOffice Can't detect JRE

Tags: centos, amazon-ec2, java, openoffice

I'm trying to run the latest version of [open office](https://www.openoffice.org/) as a service on CentOS 7.4. I downloaded the 64 bit rpm package directly from open office using wget and I'm running a 64 bit version of [amazon corretto open JDK 8](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/corretto/latest/corretto-8-ug/windows-7-install.html).

I've used the following guide to carry out the [install](https://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2010/install-openoffice-org-on-fedora-centos-red-hat-rhel/) (apart from the rpm download). When I run **openoffice4** I get the following:

```
javaldx: Could not find a Java Runtime Environment!
no suitable windowing system found, exiting.
```

What's causing this issue? I've looked online and seen reference to the wrong version of Java running but the rpm I installed is a 64 bit package so I don't believe that's the issue.

JRE path appears as follows:

```
echo $JRE_HOME

/usr/lib/jre
```

This directory doesn't exist, I tired using the below to set the JRE path but when I reboot the the java variables reset:

```
export JRE_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jre
```